# Perl Tap-Formatter-Junit problems

Tags: perl, perl-module

I'd like to run Perl tests under [Ant](http://ant.apache.org) and produce XML output in a similar format to that produced by the [JUnit Ant task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html). I tried to install the `Tap::Formatter::JUnit` module that I downloaded from http://search.cpan.org/dist/TAP-Formatter-JUnit/ and I followed the instructions described in the [README file](http://search.cpan.org/dist/TAP-Formatter-JUnit/README) and the installation completes successfully.

But when running `prove --formatter Tap::Formatter::JUnit exec.pl`, I get the following error:

```
Can't locate object method "new" via package "Tap::Formatter::JUnit" at C:/Perl/lib/TAP/Object.pm line 133.
```

Comment: What about the spaces after '::'?

Comment: no there is no space after '::'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The module is named **TAP**…, not **Tap**…. Class names are case sensitive.